# red-flag mail not showing in todo folder of outlook

Tags: outlook, mapi

We are using an Outlook plugin that utilizes MAPI in C++/vc++. However, when the 'Mail red Flag' is activated by someone, it does not display in the To-Do tasks.

expecting red flag mail should be display on to-do folder of outlook.

Is there any function or property responsible? How does outlook show emails marked as "Flagged" in TO-DO folder?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few Task-related MAPI properties that you need to set. You can see them in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - you can see the values already set (click IMessage button), or you can see which properties were added by Outlook when a message is flagged: click IMessage button, flag the message, click IMessage button again. Go to the Compare tab of the first IMessage window, and drag `PR_ENTRYID` from the second IMessage window to the Compare tab of the first IMessage. OutlookSpy will show the newly added properties:

[image]

Comment: Q) PR_FLAG_REQUEST with it's value 0x8530
     what is the use of this flag in MAPI Outlook?

Comment: That is what gets shown by Outlook on top of the preview pane in the info bar whene you select that message - "Follow up. Start by...". See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidlidflagrequest-canonical-property

Comment: i did what are the steps you shown here.. and PR_FLAG_STATUS and PR_FLAG_ICON also set by its value. still it not showing flag mail in todo.
some mail showing but some not.

findrow() returns Error 0x8004010F.  

so how can i solve this

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Either show your code or a screenshot from OutlookSpy with the properties added by your code.